# Has_many with through using factoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, factory-bot

I have this models :

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :admin_user_applications, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :admin_users, through: :admin_user_applications, :source => :user, validate: :false
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :admin_user_applications, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :administrable_applications, through: :admin_user_applications, :source => :application
end

class UserApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :application
end
```

I defined my application factory :

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :application, :class => Application do
    sequence(:name) {|n| "application-#{n}" }
    association :owner, :factory => :user
  end
end
```

But when I do this :

```
app_3 = FactoryGirl.create(:application, admin_users: [@user])
puts @user.admin_user_applications.inspect  # =>[]
```

it returns me []

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@user.admin_user_applications << FactoryGirl.create(:application)
```

Comment: Sure, it will work but I am trying to find the way to do it using FactoryGirl